# How to access Apache server from inside network?

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

Hi, I've created an Apache server and it's accessible through its domain name outside of my home network. I can also access it by going to the localhost on the PC that serves the site. My problem is that I can't access the site from any other devices connected to my network. I've tried both domain and localhost, and neither of them work. Is it possible to make the site accessible to devices within the network that its hosted on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by NAT: you have a public domain for your apache webserver, which points to your public IP. From inside your network, your apache's server cannot be reached through your public IP because of network address translation. But you apache webserver will also have a private IP address in the form of 192.168.1.X (or something similar). So, from a PC in your private network, just point to the private IP address of your apache's web server and it will work.

For completeness, I must also mention the fact that this solution relies on the settings you made in your httpd.conf file in apache: if the virtual host is mapped to *:80 (or *:port) everything will be fine

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Navigating to the private IP of the server did the trick.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to make it accessible inside of the network via its public domain name?

Comment: It's not an easy thing... when you type a public address in your browser, it's checked against a DNS to obtain its IP address. So, you should implement your own private DNS for internal usage, which resolves your public domain to your private IP. So, from outside your domain will be resolved by a public DNS, and from inside by your private DNS. This is a common setup in business environments, but maybe it's too much for an home setup

Comment: Yea sounds too complicated/unnecessary for what I currently use the server for. Thanks anyways.